# delete a package/app installed with pacman -U option

Tags: software-installation, docker, pacman, uninstall

I have installed a docker desktop application on my Arch Linux xfce4 and I want to delete it because I want to only use `docker-cli` (because the docker desktop conflicts with `docker-cli` in services and daemons).

I installed docker desktop with these steps:

1. install `docker-cli` (docker-engine,docker-compose.....all the required stuff)
2. downloaded the arch package
3. then did: `sudo pacman -U ./docker-desktop-<version>-<arch>.pkg.tar.zst`

How can I now remove this package? I have searched the internet but couldn't find a specific answer.

Comment: Doesn't `pacman -R` work? What commands did you try that failed?

Comment: What's the output of `pacman -Q | grep docker-desktop` ?

Comment: when I run pacman -Q | grep docker-desktop I find the docker-app and after that I deleted it  with -R. So Thank you so much, it was a dumb question :/

Comment: So what I should do for the post? delete it ? keep it ? (I am new to this community and this is my first post here xD)

Comment: Write an answer to your own question and accept it is the best option. and BTW : Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to query the pacman db with this cmd:

```
pacman -Q | grep docker-desktop
```

then remove it with the `-R` option or `-Rnc` in case you want to remove the dependencies also.

Note: doing this will make a conflict problem within the docker daemon (service) so in order to fix this  and use docker,u have to locate the daemon-config related to docker-desktop (maybe u will find it hidden in the you home-dir "~") and delete it.then you can install docker and use it obvis without the desktop version.